# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a service `UserService` that has a method `getUsers()` and this service is shared among different angular components.

The method calls an API and returns the data. I want to hold the result/state of last API call so I used `BehaviorSubject` to hold the last state so that if different components call `getUsers()` there should be only one API call otherwise hold state must be returned.

This is how I am implementing this

```
private _users$: BehaviorSubject<User[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this._users$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
}

getUsers(): BehaviorSubject<User[]> {
    if (!this._getUsersState().length) {
        this._loadUsers();
        this._users$.subscribe(() => {
            return this._users$;
        });
    } else {
        return this._users$;
    }
}

_loadUsers() {
    let _users$ = this.http.get(`${this._context}/users/`);
    _users$.subscribe((users: User[]) => {
        this._users$.next(Object.assign([], users));
    });
}

_getUsersState(): User[] {
    return this._users$.getValue();
}
```

And in the component

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: any) => {
    console.log(users);
});
```

but I am getting the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

I guess get users returns automatically if the length is 0.

How can I solve this issue? And is this approach good?

Comment: Can you check if the `this._users$.subscribe` is called before or after the `_loadUser` has parsed the result of the observable? To me, the problem is that you execute the function before the subscribe function on _loadUsers has finished its job

Comment: Thanks but the error is from the component and even if the method is called before the `_loadUser` then it is returning the `BehaviourSubject` so no error.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your service like this :

```
private _users$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>(null);
public usersChanged = this._users$.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getUsers(): BehaviorSubject<User[]> {
    if (!this._getUsersState().length) {
        this._loadUsers();
        this._users$.subscribe(() => {
            return this._users$;
        });
    } else {
        return this._users$;
    }
}

_loadUsers() {
    let _users$ = this.http.get(`${this._context}/users/`);
    _users$.subscribe((users: User[]) => {
        this._users$.next(Object.assign([], users));
    });
}

_getUsersState(): User[] {
    return this._users$.getValue();
}
```

edit yout component logic like this:

```
this.userService.usersChanged
.subscribe((users: any) => {
  if(!!users){
    console.log(users);
  } else {
    console.log("No user found!");
  }
});
```

It's a good practise to have a variable that is an observable of your `private` behaviorSubject. So you just subscribe to it and whenever its state change, it'll emit.

Comment: this could be the way, but in service there will be other methods too so component will call like service to addUser, getUsers, what about this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

getUsers method should return a observable and it's not good practice to subscribe observable in service.
If you want to maintain state of users then use a singleton service. Declare property in service like this:

```
public users: Users[] = [];


private getUsers(): Observable<Users[]> {
 if (!this.users.length) {
   return this.http.get(`${this._context}/users/`);
 }
 return Observable.of(this.users);
}
```

In your component

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: User[]) => {
    this.userService.users = users; // (or users.slice(0)
    console.log(users);
});
```

Comment: service is the one who provides data why component will feed data that was returned through service itself?

Comment: Your point is not absolutely right. I just created a store service. That's the way redux also works. But you should never subscribe in your service because you will not able to unsubscribe. If you will not unsubscribe there will be a memory leakage.